# fish shellでの記載方法

Tags: linux, bash, fish

.bashrc に以下のように dockerサービスが起動してない場合、サービス起動するようにしているのですが、
fish の場合、どのように記載するべきなのでしょうか？

```
service docker status > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    sudo service docker start
fi
```

Comment: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#configuration によると、
`~/.config/fish/config.fish`がfishでの.bashrcに当たるようです。

dockerの記述を、上記`config.fish`に書いてみたらどうでしょう

Answer (score 0):

一応、自己解決。
ubuntu20.04 fish shell だと以下の方法で期待通りの動作となりました。
fish の場合、「service docker status > /dev/null 2>&1」の箇所がもっとスマートに記載できる気がしますが、わかりませんでした。。。
※$status の比較値を1を3にしてますが、ubuntu20.04の場合は3にする必要がありました。

```
service docker status > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $status = 3 ]
    sudo service docker start
end
```